# Alarms are not getting fired in real time scenario

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have set alarms for monday to friday. Alarms are set for a particular period of time like 10:00 to 11 AM, when this time comes Alarms get fired randomly. It is working fine when we change the device date and time settings manually but in real time when actually a particular date comes it does not gets fired.

Here is the code i am using fo`enter code here`r setting the pending intent for alarms-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class).putExtra("WeekDay", weekORWeekned);
        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putString("WeekDay", weekORWeekned);
        extras.putLong("ActivateAlarmTime", mills);
        intent.putExtras(extras);

        intent.setData(Uri.parse(""+alarmId));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int) alarmId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); 
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,mills,AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
```

where AlarmReceiver works as a BroadcastReceiver for the event and "mills" is the time for the alarm to be fired every monday to friday.

Comment: what exactly do You mean with "particular date comes" ? Do You mean, let´s say the alarm has to fire at 9:00 am, but then it get´s fired later?

Comment: i meant if i have set an alarm for 9.00 am on monday it has to repeat from monday to fri for the whole year. But what happens is if i change the device date it fires exactly at 9.00 am but in real time it is not getting fired.

Comment: ok, but there is no option to fix this, because the alarmManager is always getting the time from Your device. If device´s time is changed, it´s always orientating on that changed time. But what You can do is, that You can listen to the time_changed event with a broadcast receiver. Then You can recalculate the real time and reset the alarm manager.